# CSS Box Model Chrome border color

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to reproduce what is happening in fiddle but I am not able to do that.

I have a code similar to this

```
html{
    font-size: 2em;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

table td{
    background: #d0d0d0;
    border: 10px solid white;
}

<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody> 
                        <tr class="row1_fixed">
                            <td>Row header 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row2_fixed">
                            <td>Row header 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row3_fixed">
                            <td>Row header 3</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Column data 1
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Column data 1
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Column data 2
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Column data 2
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Column data 3
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Column data 3
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/agusgambina/P4mQy/12/

I want the cells be spaced by the white border.

In firefox works well

[image: Firefox]

But in Chrome appears something like a second border with the background color

[image: Chrome]

Thanks

Comment: the fiddle you gave works fine in chrome and Firefox. is that your code in fiddle?

Comment: @dippas My code is similar to that but not that, as I wrote, I am not able to reproduce the same behaviour on fiddle. Thanks

Comment: so show us your code instead of an example in a fiddle. Because that fiddle and code you showed here is working fine.

Comment: @dippas I don't understand why in the code of fiddlejs appear the grey lines in the middle of the table, that is my problem. On the other hand, the html and css don;t reproduce the error, but yes when I am running the application, I am using nodejs and angularjs, but I don't think the problem is there. Thank you

Comment: just put your code here or make a fiddle..even with that grey lines (errors), so we can try helping you.

Comment: dippas here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/agusgambina/P4mQy/17/ thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented the property

```
.compare table .column-item{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And the line stopped showing.

Answer (score 1):

Im not so sure if this is what you are looking for, but here is your modified
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P4mQy/19)**

It has some behavior in Chrome and Firefox

I changed your `.compare table` and your `.column-item`

Hope it helps you.